# I couldn't dynamically allocate 2D array in a function

Tags: c++

I try to dynamically allocate my 2D array by passing to function,but it doesn't get that size.

Could you say me please, where is my mistake?

```cpp
bool b_alloc_table_2_dim(int** piTable, int iSizeX, int iSizeY)
{

    if ((iSizeX < 0) || (iSizeY < 0))
        return false;

    piTable = new int*[iSizeX];

    for (int i = 0; i < iSizeX; i++)

        piTable[i] = new int[iSizeY];

    return true;
}

int main()
{

    int** pi_table;

    cout << "Allocation Result :" << b_alloc_table_2_dim(pi_table, 5, 3) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider using a `std::vector` instead of this error prone approach with `new` and a missing `delete[]` even. It would be way easier for you to work with, and also safer and less prone for errors.

Comment: You need to send address of `pi_table` to `b_alloc_table_2_dim()`. Otherwise allocated address will be lost resulting in a memory leak

Comment: @Carl I deallocate it in other function and I will not use std::vector according to the task.

Comment: @kuro I didn't pass the address of it? So how to pass it to the function?

Comment: As @Ayjay mentioned, you can use a reference or you can send address of `pi_table` like `b_alloc_table_2_dim (&pi_table, 5, 3)`. Then you have to change the function definition and body accordingly

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify an argument to a function, you need to pass it by reference or pointer. Change your function signature to this:

```
bool b_alloc_table_2_dim(int**& piTable, int iSizeX, int iSizeY) {
```